# How to remove bar under tab in active editor

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've been struggling to find where to disable the bar that tells me where I am in the class in Intellij.

[image: Bar to remove]

Anyone knows how to disable this bar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Settings | Editor | Appearance | [ ] Show HTML breadcrumbs

Comment: No wonder why I was struggling finding it! This is not HTML for me!

Comment: Yes, the name is kind of confusing.

Comment: In Intellij 2016.2 this option can be found in `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show breadcrumbs`